# How to satisfy flow with union type of date or object

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have the following type:

```
export type dateParts = { day?: string, month?: string, year?: string };

export type dateOrObject = Date | dateParts;
```

Then I have a DatePicker component:

```
export class DatePicker extends Component {
  props: {
    value?: dateOrObject,
  };
```

But when I try and deconstruct `value` when it is an object:

```
if (!isDate(value)) {
  const { day, month, year } = value;

  this.state = {
    day,
    month,
    year
  };

  return;
}
```

I get this error:

```
const { day, month, year } = value;
                               ^^^^ property `year`. Property not found in
const { day, month, year } = value;
                                        ^^^^^ Date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Disjoint unions require you to use a single property to distinguish
>   each object type. You cannot distinguish two different objects by
>   different properties.

Flow doesn't know in your case what `isDate` function is about. So it's better to use simple property checking.

```
if (value.year) {
  const { day, month, year } = value;

  this.state = {
    day,
    month,
    year
 };

 return;
}
```

Update, above doesn't work, though it follows the official docs.

Try this one instead :

```
! (value instanceof Date)
```

Comment: I still get the same error with the new condition `if (value.year)`

Comment: are you using this.props.value?